# How to use firebase login with email and password on Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

When I tried to follow the Firebase website for tutorial (https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/login/password.html)  on developing a simple login on android studio, I faced error, with red wiggly lines.

Could someone help me or suggest a good place to learn about step by step tutorial on how to create a simple login using firebase. Resources on firebase login for android are very limited online. Would be great if someone could help me .

This is the code copied from firebase website for login, when I paste it into my code I have red error on email password function error UserData etc etc.

```
   mRef.createUser({
            email    : "bobtony@firebase.com",
            password : "correcthorsebatterystaple"
    }, function(error, userData) {
        if (error) {
            console.log("Error creating user:", error);
        } else {
            console.log("Successfully created user account with uid:", userData.uid);
        }
    });
```

Comment: The code you have copy/pasted is for use in a web site. You indicate you are using Android, so need to look at the [Firebase guide for Android](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/login/password.html). Given your problem, you're probable better off following a tutorial like this one: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/codelabs/chat

Comment: Hi sir, thanks for the extremely detailed and well written tutorial, helped me alot :) , anyway when i came to the end of the tutorial, it had a next step to add logout button and a password reset button, when can i learn about that?

Comment: The codelab explains that too. Take it, don't skim it.

Comment: where's the link to that "next steps" where you teach to add logout button, reset button, using a recycler view. The link you provided me is just on chatting and login, how to go on to the next tutorial

Comment: That is the complete tutorial. The "Next steps" section is a list of things you can do on your own.

Comment: Hi, for your tutorial you had a setEnabledAuthProvider(AuthProviderType.PASSWORD); i cannot seem to type AuthProviderType i only can type AuthProvider why is that so

Comment: Checkout https://androidbeasts.wordpress.com/2018/06/19/firebase-login-using-email-and-password/

Answer (score 0):

```
ref.createUser("bobtony@firebase.com", "correcthorsebatterystaple", new Firebase.ValueResultHandler<Map<String, Object>>() { @Override public void onSuccess(Map<String, Object> result) { System.out.println("Successfully created user account with uid: " + result.get("uid")); } @Override public void onError(FirebaseError firebaseError) { // there was an error }
```

Sorry about it being on one line, I'm currently on a phone and it's not working well with code
I got the code from https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/login/password.html

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above Firebase has a library https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android that has useful tools including login. Sounds like you went through the code lab posted by Frank van Puffelen.

If it is helpful, I have been working on a project that uses their library but adds additional functionality like new user registration, saving user data (like the new users name) into your Firebase database, etc and with, hopefully, easy implementation. I have step by step instructions on how to add my code to your project with my base example the code added to a blank Android project.

The project includes Google Auth as well. https://github.com/cardenuto/FirebaseLogin